# Simultaneous GridView button events/determining which button has been touched

Tags: android, gridview, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. I have a gridview of 8 buttons. At the moment I'm using an onItemClickListener to trigger the buttons actions, however this produces two problems for me.

1) The buttons action happens after the button has been unpressed.

2) Two buttons cannot the pressed at the same time, you must release the first button.

As I have learnt, an onTouchListener should resolve my first issue, though I'm not sure how to determine which button has been pressed. My code for the onItemClickListener is as follows

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
        });
```

Now with the above, I know exactly which button has been pushed. I believe the code for implementing as an onTouchListener is as follows

```
        gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    }) {
```

How am I supposed to determine which button has been pressed using MotionEvent? Before I was getting passed 'position' and it made this fairly easy. I also need to account for if two or more buttons have been pushed simultaneously/without letting another one go.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Having hit this very issue recently and coming across this post in my quest for help, I wanted to add two things from what I did which seem to have worked:

1) I added the onTouchListener to the object in the adapter rather than the activity or gridview.

2) In the OnTouchListener, I looked for MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN (first finger touch) and MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN (subsequent finger touches), this way I can get multitouches and process them immediately without waiting for the user to lift their finger(s).

Note that I called it ImageAdapter, even though I've added a TextView to each as that way I can use the TextView background for the image, but add invisible text to the TextView so it works with Talkback):

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return numCols * numRows;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new TextView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            textView = new TextView(mContext);

        } else {
            textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        // place any other initial setup needed for the TextView here

        // here's our onTouchListener
        textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                boolean returnValue;
                int thePosition = v.getId();

                // MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN gets the first touch
                // MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN gets any subsequent touches (if you place a second finger on the screen)
                // Between these I can get touches as soon as they happen, including multitouch support, without needing to wait until the user lifts their finger.

                if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)) {
                    TextView textView;
                    if (v == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                        textView = new TextView(mContext);

                    } else {
                        textView = (TextView) v;
                    }

                    // Do any processing based on the touch - I call a function and pass the position (number of cell, 1..n) and textview so can make changes to it as needed
                    ScreenTapped(thePosition, textView);
                    // I used a returnValue
                    returnValue = true;
                } else returnValue = false;

                return returnValue;

        });
        return textView;

    } // getView
} //imageadapter
```

Answer (score 0):

I am infact trying to figure the same thing out.  I got as far as figuring out which gridcell has been clicked using the following code

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

            float currentXPosition = me.getX();
            float currentYPosition = me.getY();
            int position = gridView.pointToPosition((int) currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);
```

Position gives you the number on the gridView, and you can supposedly retrieve that particular item as following

```
gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

But that is where I am stuck.  My gridView has Textview items in it, and I am having trouble converting the item to a textview and then performing operations on it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When using gridView the philosophy is:

- the grid view implements the onTouchLister
- when touch happens onTouchLister  gathers the coordinates (a lot :) )
  for all ACTION_MOVE events
- when the touch event is MOVE_UP, calculate the real positions under
  the coordinates and return the item in the grid

So the solution would be:

In your activity where you have **findViewById(some_grid_view)**

```
//Register handler for the onTouch event of gridView in your activity
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new MyActivityOnTouchListener(this));
```

*NOTE*: my onTouch listener is implemented in another class (MyActivityOnTouchListener) instead of inside the activity

...then in the MyActivityOnTouchListener class you implement the **onTouch** method:

```
public class CalendarActivityOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private MyActivity myActivityContext; 
    private GridView mGridView;
    private HashSet<Point> movementCoordinates = new HashSet<Point>;

    //Constructor
    public MyActivityOnTouchListener (MyActivity context){
        this.myActivityContext= context;
        mGridView= myActivityContext.getGridView();  //assign touched gridView into a local variable
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    /*
     *   NOTE: 
     *    ACTION_MOVE fires events until you release it
     *    ACTION_UP once you release it fires it   
     */

    //while touching the grid a bunch of ACTION_MOVE events are dispatched
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
       //gather all coordinates touched (in a set to avoid duplicates)
       movementCoordinates.add(new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()));
       return true;
    }

    //Finally the finger is lifted   
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

         //convert all movementCoordinates gathered in the previous block into real grid positions
        int position;
        for(Point p : movementCoordinates){
            Log.d("Luka", p.x +" / "+p.y);
            position = calendarGridView.pointToPosition(p.x, p.y);

            //...Do whatever with the position
        }
    }
  }
```

}

Be careful about the *pointToPosition()* method because in some cases it can return -1 instead of the position behind the coordinates. For example, if you have a margin between items in the grid those coordinates cannot return a position, hence the -1

hope it helps...